# Show div when google map is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using google map api in my rails app and I would like to show a div with jquery when someone is using the map.

The map is contained in a div with the id search_map_container so what I tryed

```
$('#search_map_container').click(function() {
    $('#my_div').show();
});
```

But it fail. And it also fail with `.focus()`, `.focusin()`, `.mouseenter()` or `.change()` events.

For putvande : 
My html is a simple div :

```
<div id='my_div' style='display:none;'>
    This is a test
</div>
```

And google map html is generate by google :

```
<div class="search_map_container"> 
  <div id="search_map" class="gmaps4rails_map" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
  ...
  Google map code
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

For  Bharat Soni :
I mean when someone click on google map or scroll or zoom.

Comment: Can you show your HTML and CSS?

Comment: could you pls share ur code in fiddle? or share your html and css?

Comment: by "using map", what do you mean... do you mean when somebody clicked on google map ??

Comment: And what about `#search_map_container`? Is that hidden? Can you show that element too?#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container you try to click on does not have an `id` 'search_map_container' but a `class` 'search_map_container'. So it should be :

```
$('.search_map_container').click(function() {
    $('#my_div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Google map event listeners:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
  $('#my_div').show();
});


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  $('#my_div').show();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
   $('#my_div').show();
});
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RSBgP/